# Find frequency of data in sql server 2014 by date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

so here is a question.

I have a table `FacebookInfo` with a column `name`.

Another table is `FacebookPost` with a column `created_time` and foriegn key as `facebookinfoid` mapped to FacebookInfo `Id` column

So basically `FacebookInfo` has a record of Facebook Pages and `FacebookPost` is the posts of those facebook pages.

What I want to find out is `how frequently the pages are posting on Facebook`, so I want to find out the average posts per day, the difference in hours between those posts, average time on first post of a day and average time on last post of the day.

Thanks for help.

Here is some sample data

FacebookInfo

```
id  name
3   Qatar Airways
4   KLM Royal Dutch Airlines
5   LATAM Airlines
6   Southwest Airlines
```

FacebookPost

```
id  facebookinfoid  created_time
777 3   2016-12-06 12:54:31.000
778 3   2016-12-05 09:54:09.000
779 3   2016-12-02 12:40:46.000
780 3   2016-12-01 13:00:00.000
781 3   2016-11-30 11:29:53.000
782 3   2016-11-30 09:00:00.000
783 3   2016-11-29 10:09:45.000
784 3   2016-11-28 14:00:00.000
785 3   2016-11-27 11:21:11.000
786 3   2016-11-26 12:00:01.000
787 3   2016-11-25 11:58:55.000
788 3   2016-11-24 10:28:19.000
789 3   2016-11-23 16:20:29.000
790 3   2016-11-23 11:19:42.000
791 3   2016-11-21 12:03:07.000
792 3   2016-11-18 13:36:41.000
793 3   2016-11-17 11:08:41.000
794 3   2016-11-16 12:01:00.000
795 3   2016-11-15 13:39:06.000
796 3   2016-11-11 15:11:56.000
1454    4   2016-12-06 15:00:22.000
1455    4   2016-12-05 14:59:04.000
1456    4   2016-12-05 09:00:07.000
1457    4   2016-12-04 15:00:07.000
1458    4   2016-12-03 10:00:08.000
1459    4   2016-12-02 15:00:15.000
1460    4   2016-12-01 14:00:00.000
1461    4   2016-11-30 13:30:24.000
1462    4   2016-11-29 15:00:07.000
1463    4   2016-11-28 15:00:19.000
1464    4   2016-11-28 09:00:09.000
1465    4   2016-11-26 10:00:06.000
1466    4   2016-11-24 15:00:04.000
1467    4   2016-11-23 09:00:09.000
1468    4   2016-11-22 15:01:04.000
1469    4   2016-11-21 15:00:07.000
1470    4   2016-11-21 05:00:10.000
1471    4   2016-11-19 10:00:07.000
1472    4   2016-11-18 09:00:10.000
1473    4   2016-11-17 15:00:01.000
2454    5   2016-12-05 16:00:01.000
2455    5   2016-12-02 16:02:37.000
2456    5   2016-12-01 16:00:09.000
2457    5   2016-11-30 16:00:48.000
2458    5   2016-11-29 16:01:34.000
2459    5   2016-11-28 16:00:00.000
2460    5   2016-11-25 16:00:01.000
2461    5   2016-11-23 16:00:00.000
2462    5   2016-11-22 16:00:00.000
2463    5   2016-11-21 16:00:00.000
2464    5   2016-11-19 16:00:03.000
2465    5   2016-11-18 16:00:00.000
2466    5   2016-11-17 16:00:01.000
2467    5   2016-11-16 16:00:03.000
2468    5   2016-11-15 16:00:01.000
2469    5   2016-11-12 16:00:00.000
2470    5   2016-11-11 16:00:00.000
2471    5   2016-11-10 16:00:01.000
2472    5   2016-11-09 16:00:00.000
2473    5   2016-11-08 16:00:02.000
3059    6   2016-12-06 15:14:30.000
3060    6   2016-12-04 21:38:33.000
3061    6   2016-12-03 22:27:40.000
3062    6   2016-12-02 21:29:42.000
3063    6   2016-12-01 23:00:04.000
3064    6   2016-11-30 22:00:02.000
3065    6   2016-11-30 20:28:17.000
3066    6   2016-11-29 17:57:02.000
3067    6   2016-11-28 20:49:59.000
3068    6   2016-11-26 17:10:55.000
3069    6   2016-11-26 12:50:45.000
3070    6   2016-11-25 21:16:31.000
3071    6   2016-11-25 01:27:09.000
3072    6   2016-11-24 15:50:16.000
3073    6   2016-11-23 22:00:01.000
3074    6   2016-11-23 15:10:32.000
3075    6   2016-11-22 21:42:42.000
3076    6   2016-11-22 16:29:28.000
3077    6   2016-11-22 03:03:21.000
3078    6   2016-11-22 01:45:41.000
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: You can group by calendar date and facebookpageid, THEN you can get MIN(created_time),MAX(created_time), COUNT(created_time), DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(created_time),MAX(created_time)) / (COUNT(created_time) - 1) AS AverageTimeBetweenPostsInDay

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, sql is not my strongest point.

Comment: No one knows what to do? Come on guys, there are so many "experts" here.